# Custom Unity launcher localization

Tags: unity, localization

I would like to localize Unity launcher using **own** texts. At the very least I would like to change "play!", "quit", "Graphics" and "Input" to own arbitrary labels. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends of your OS :

- If you are running on **OS X** you can use Interface Builder to create your own launcher interface.
- If you are on **Windows** you will have to create a special [configuration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html) so that your game launches automatically without having a launcher window. If you really want to change the buttons text and design you could also use some software like [ResHacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/), it is a bit tricky but I guess it should do the job.

Regardless of your OS you can modify the 'Graphics' part of your launcher as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html).

Comment: The buttons text would do, if I started meddling with style, I could as well re-write the whole launcher. Do I understand you correctly that the only way is resource hacking? (I was unable to find localization in the linked configuration manuals)